# Knockout js: is it possible to get the bindiing object attached to a HTML element from the HTML tag iteself

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

If i have a foreach loop in knockoutjs:

```
<!-- ko foreach: messageModels() -->


                    <li>
                        <a data-bind="click:$parent.startChat.bind(), css: unreadMessagesCount() > 0 ? 'unread' : 'nothing'" style="cursor: pointer" href="#" >
                            <div class="media">
                                <div class="pull-left">
                                    <img class="media-object img-circle" src="assets/images/ici-avatar.jpg">
                                    <!-- ko if: unreadMessagesCount() > 0 -->
                                    <span class="badge badge-red" data-bind="text:unreadMessagesCount()">1</span>
                                    <!-- /ko -->
                                </div>
                                <div class="media-body">
                                    <p class="media-heading"><span  data-bind="text:friend.userName()">Ing. Imrich Kamarel</span> <span class="time" data-bind="text: $parent.convertTime(messages()[messages().length - 1].dateCreated())">12:44</span></p>
                                    <span class="message" data-bind="text:messages()[messages().length - 1].message()">Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin commodo. Cras purus odio, vestibulum in vulputate at, tempus viverra turpis. Fusce condimentum nunc ac nisi vulputate fringilla. Donec lacinia congue felis in faucibus.</span>
                                    <div class="chat-actions">
                                        <span class="mark-unread" title="Mark as unread"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i></span>
                                        <span class="archive" title="Archive"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <!-- /ko -->
```

if i get a hold of the li tag in the foreachloop using a jquery selector,  is it possible to get the object that was bound to it by the foreach loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible using `ko.dataFor`. For example: `ko.dataFor($("li")[0])` returns the viewmodel bound to your first list item.

*However*, you shouldn't really need `ko.dataFor` in your production code if you follow knockout's desired architecture patterns... I use `ko.dataFor` a lot, but mostly for debugging purposes.

You might want to explain *why* you need to figure out the binding context of an element, because there's probably a better solution to your problem.

Comment: i have a scroll box and what the check the <li> tags that are visible in the scroll box, so that i can mark them as read

Comment: A better solution would be to add a [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) to the `<li>` that has direct access to the `$data` and the `element`. In the custom binding, you add an event listener to scrolls and check the element's visibility. If it's visible, you can directly set an observable `isRead` property to `true`.

Comment: mehn, i am so new to this custom binding, and frankly it seems difficult

Comment: finally gotten the hang of custom binding after going through the documentation , thanks.